# change method to Runtime Exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I have a method, in which right now I am handling the exception using the try catch method.

I have a custom exception method to handle the error.

Now I have to change this exception handling to runtime exception.

Code:

```
public class AppException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8674749112864599715L;

    public AppException() {
    }

    public AppException(String message, Throwable cause,
            boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    }

    public AppException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public AppException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public AppException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Method which handled using try catch.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
public String save(StagingDocument stagingData)
        throws AppException {
    String enrichObjectId = null;
    try {
        EnrichDocument document = getEnrichDocument(stagingData);
        EnrichDocument enrichPayload = enrichStagingDocumentRepository
                .save(document);
        enrichObjectId = enrichPayload.getId().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("EXCEPTION IN SAVETOENRICHDOCUMENT METHOD: " + e);
        throw new AppException (e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
    return enrichObjectId;
}
```

Here in the above method is the implementation when `AppException extends` the `Exception class`.

Now I need to change the save method according to `runtime exception` handling.

Question:

1. How can I change this method,without using `try catch` method?
2. If try catch is not there how the `exception` is get handled?

Comment: Why is your exception abstract?  That doesn't make sense (you won't be able to directly instantiate it, for one).

Comment: @Makoto Sorry typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a `try-catch` block, the original `Exception` would not be caught. If it is a `RuntimeException`, you will get no compilation errors as `RuntimeExeption` does not need to be caught. If that `Exception` occurs, it will simply be thrown from the `save()` method (it will be delegated).

If the original `Exception` is not a `RuntimeException` and you don't want to use a `try-catch` block, you may declare the `save()` method to throw that `Exception` but in this case it will obviously be not an instance of `AppException` but the original exception itself.

Btw, if you create an `AppException`, its cause should be `e` and not `e.getCause()`. If you pass `e.getCause()` as the cause of your `AppException`, then `e` itself will be lost. You might also want to add a custom error message and not use the original exception's message.

**Summary:** if you want your `save()` method to throw an instance of `AppException` if an `Exception` is encountered inside, you can't do that without a `try-catch` block, you have to catch it (the `Exception` encountered inside) and wrap it in a new `AppException` like you did.

Answer (score 0):

`RuntimeException`s don't have to be declared in the method signature, and if you want to remove the try/catch blocks as well - you can do it:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
public String save(StagingDocument stagingData) {
        String enrichObjectId = null;
        EnrichDocument document = getEnrichDocument(stagingData);
        EnrichDocument enrichPayload = enrichStagingDocumentRepository
                .save(document);
        enrichObjectId = enrichPayload.getId().toString();
        return enrichObjectId;
}
```

When there's no try/catch - the exception doesn't get "handled" it is rather getting cascaded until either a higher level handles it or until the highest level exists the program (with the `RuntimeException`).

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime exceptions` need not be caught. If you are using `AppException` as a checked exception, still you need not put `try/catch` since you have already handled it using `throws` in the method signature. The method which is calling `save()` will have to handle the `AppException`.